# Counting persons in each age range

Tags: java

I am calculating the number of people within a given age range. This is my current approach.

Note:

- The `persons` is a `List<Person>`
- The `getDiffYears()` returns the number of years between now and DOB of the person. It includes the month and day as well.
- The method will be returning a `HashMap<String, Integer>()` (Can be changed if there is a better alternative.)

The code has been tested and is working. I wanted to know if there is a more efficient approach without using this many if statements?

```
for (Person p: persons) {
 Date dob = p.getDob();
 if (dob != null) {
  years = getDiffYears(p.getDob());
  if (years < 10) {
   a++;
  } else if (years < 20) {
   b++;
  } else if (years < 30) {
   c++;
  } else if (years < 40) {
   d++;
  } else if (years < 50) {
   e++;
  } else if (years < 60) {
   f++;
  } else if (years < 70) {
   g++;
  } else if (years < 80) {
   h++;
  } else if (years < 90) {
   i++;
  } else if (years < 100) {
   j++;
  } else {
   k++;
  }
 } else {
  k++;
 }
}
map.put("00 - 09", a);
map.put("10 - 19", a);
map.put("20 - 29", b);
map.put("30 - 39", c);
map.put("40 - 49", e);
map.put("50 - 59", f);
map.put("60 - 69", g);
map.put("70 - 79", h);
map.put("80 - 89", i);
map.put("90 - 99", j);
map.put("Unknown", k);
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Are you on Java 8?

Comment: I would argue that being over 100 is not unknown just in the category 100+. Since you're using range maybe 100-infinity (I know it's useful for you probably, I'm just pointing it out)

Comment: @h.j.k. Yes, I am on Java 8.

Comment: @Marc-Andre I have them in the same variable as the count won't be used for anything. It is there to simply know how many people's age were not used.

Comment: @miqdadamirali I do understand this but I just wanted to point out that classifying people over 100 in a category Unknown is not accurate since you do know their age and in which "range" they are. I suspected you did not use that "range" and why you put it in an unused category.

Comment: @Marc-Andre Would you suggest separating them. A count for 100+ and another for Unknown? It does make sense having them separate.

Comment: @miqdadamirali Strictly speaking, yeah I think it's better to separate them. Is is really useful, it's up to you to decide. Would you use this new point of data ? I don't know, but I don't think adding a new range for 100+ would be harmful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you have a typo with your values. You accidentally have `a` twice when putting to your map, and then you end up missing `d`:

```
map.put("00 - 09", a);
map.put("10 - 19", a);
map.put("20 - 29", b);
map.put("30 - 39", c);
map.put("40 - 49", e);
```

These single letter variables aren't helping you. Instead have an `int` array that you increment. You could then just increment by index, and since you're using a simple numerical set up, you could just use `years/10` as your index.

Something like this:

```
int counts[] = new int[11];
if (years == null or years > 100){
    counts[10]++;
} else {
    counts[years/10]++;
}
```

`int`s are rounded down so if `years = 19` then you get `19/10`, which is `1`.

You can then use these values for your mapping:

```
map.put("00 - 09", counts[0]);
map.put("10 - 19", counts[1]);
map.put("20 - 29", counts[2]);
```

I'm sure there's a way to loop over those or make the mapping more directly, but I'm not personally familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake :). 1. The issue I run into when using the array is that I do not have the option of also storing the range the count corresponds to. 
2. A number such as 15, when divided by 10. Would the result be rounded up or down? because you can't have value at index position 1.5.

Comment: @miqdadamirali integers are rounded down, so even 19/10 becomes 1. Also I wasn't suggesting you just keep the array, I intended for you to then use `put`at the end with the array values. I'll amend both these notes.

Comment: You made a good point. I'll wait out a day and see if someone else responds. Thanks

Comment: Aren't the indices 0-10 (so 11 elements?) Wouldn't [11] overflow?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You are correct, I rounded it right at first then did it wrong when figuring out what index "Unknown" should be.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering if it was a clever ruse to generate an ArrayOndexOutOfBounds - you might want to mention the name of this sort of data by the way - "Histogram"

Answer (score 11):

#### Java 8 streams

Aside from the typos pointed out by [@SuperBiasedMan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/116230/24141), you can use Java 8's stream-based processing as an alternative for generating your `Map` result.

```
private static final int UPPER_LIMIT = 100;
private static final String[] KEYS = new String[]{ "00 - 09", /* ... */ "Unknown" };

private static int categorize(int year) {
    return Math.min(year, UPPER_LIMIT) / 10;
}

Map<String, Long> results = persons.stream()
                    .map(Person::getDob)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(ThisClass::getDiffYears)
                    .map(ThisClass::categorize)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ageCategory -> KEYS[ageCategory],
                                Collectors.counting()));
```

1. Define the `UPPER_LIMIT` of your age categorization and the desired category names.
2. From a `Stream` of your `Person` objects, [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to their birthdays by calling `Person::getDob` as [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).
3. [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) `null` birthdays by using [`Objects::nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-).
4. [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) birthdays to ages by calling your `getDiffYears(Date)` method. Note that if it is *not* a `static` method, the method reference then becomes `this::getDiffYears`.
5. [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) ages to the age category by calling `categorize(int)` to get the desired array indices for `KEYS`. If you have not realized yet, `ThisClass` is just a placeholder for the actual class name.
6. [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) the age categories into the desired `Map` result [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) our categorization and [`counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) the elements per category.

#### Other advice

- Your method should return a `Map` instead of `HashMap` so that callers of this method only need to deal with the *interface*, and not the implementation.
- You may want to consider how to handle for `null` inputs to `getDiffYear(Date)`. Should it return a negative value?
- You can also experiment with deriving the category names in a programmatic manner, instead of using literal `String`s.
- You can even think about making your age categorization depend on a configurable upper limit (100) and band (10). For example, how easy will it be to treat the upper limit as 101 (`UPPER_LIMIT = 101`) and a band of 11 years per category (hint: take a closer look at the suggested code...)?